# jQuery AJAX parses HTML response as JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, cakephp

I cant find anything on the web about this mysterious bug. I wrote a simple Ajax calling a CakePHP Controller-Function to render a simple View. Finally i want to put that rendered HTML into a Popup:

**The Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('base').attr('href') + '/myController/renderPopupContent/' + this.view,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    context: this,
    success: function( data ) {
        this.content = data;
        this.show();
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
        showMessage(status, xhr);
    }
});
```

Now i get a **jQuery-Error** which says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

This is because jQuery tries to (automatically^^) parse the response as JSON. If i debug the script it breaks at **jQuery (1.9.1) at Line 541** and it really tries to parse that html-response (STRING!) into/from JSON.

How can i avoid this and get jquery known of the dataType "HTML"

**Additional Info:**

The jQuery-Error (@Ln541) occures after an "alert();" in my success-callback, so the Ajax is  already done when the error is thrown.

Comment: Please read what i wrote: Its NOT a syntax Error. I debugged the jquery script at the line where it tries to parse the response as JSON and the string tried to parse is my HTML-Response. So it does what it does to JSON-responses (automatically) even to this HTML-Response.

Comment: `console.log(data);` what does it outputs? can you share?

Comment: This will output my retrieved HTML-Response in the Console. "<div>..</div>"

Comment: May you create a jsFiddle showcasing the issue? In a quick test it worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/D588A/

Comment: Did you check the response header? Which MIME type does it show? I guess it's something like `application/json`. In that case you'd need to edit the header settings on the server

Comment: Chrome Dev-Tools say:
Content-Type:text/html;

Comment: Nevermind - Wrote solution in my Question

Comment: I highly recommend using a more stable approach with extenion (.json) URLs and JSON: http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/

Comment: You just saved me from shaving my head to avoid pulling the rest of my hair out. I had the exact same thing occurring. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, so at least I'm the one with the bald head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in another JS-File i found this snippet:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(evt, xhr, options) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(xhr['responseText']);
```

This obviously fires after every ajax and tries parsing the response.